# Apply same query string paramter to all my links in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I am using the query string to decide what database my MVC application should use.

http://localhost/control_groups?server=test-server

So I made an ApplicationController, which is a superclass for all my other controllers, it grabs this parameter each time and put it in the ViewBag.

But then need to add the parameter to all my links. It seems to be a lot of work to add them manually like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Control types", "Index", "control_types", new { server = ViewBag.ServerName},null)</li>
```

Is there a smarter way to automatically set this for all generated links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension for HTMLHelper

```
public static class ActionLinkExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        //Add the server=test-server to all action link
        routeDictionary.Add("server", "test-server");
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeDictionary, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }
}
```

And use the extension method in razor view

```
<li>@Html.CustomActionLink("Control types", "Index", "control_types", null, null)</li>
```

Comment: still he will need to replace all Action Links with Custom one, though it is a good way

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking it might be better to store the selected db server in a cookie or session instead. Any opinion on that?

Comment: I think storing it in session is a better choice.

Comment: Yep, went for the session storing instead.